# Ads don't load in my unity game and when they do, the game crashes after they finish

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

My unity game uses AdMob rewarded ads. In the Unity Editor, they worked perfectly, but when tested on an Android device, they didn't load. Later I found out that when I use ARMv7 with Mono instead of ARM64, they do load, however, the game crashes when the ad is over. Testing ads work even with ARMv7 selected, but they cause the game to crash, too.

I've tried changing API, scripting backend to mono, and experimenting with Publishing and Other setting. I have also checked Ad Unit ID and App ID. Honestly, I didn't know what to expect, it was just pure hope to accidentaly find the solution.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, I used IEnumerator with WaitForEndOfFrame when the ad finished, it is working perfectly now